# Correct Wiring for Furnace Blower Motor

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, thermostat

After getting my furnace blower motor replaced, it now runs only in the following scenarios:

1. Mode "Cool" Fan "Auto"
2. Mode "Cool" Fan "On"
3. Mode "Heat" Fan "On"

In other words it will not run when in "Heat" mode with Fan "Auto". I believe it could have something to do with the way the motor is wired.

Please see the images and link below for information on how it is currently wired. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as we are moving into winter quickly here!

**[Click here for Furnace and Blower Motor Information](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s108/sh/d09ac37f-f49d-44ca-8787-e273a992fc8f/256a6d758890d63d)**

**Wires Coming from Original Furnace**
[image]

**Wires Coming from new Blower Motor**
[image]

**How the wires are connected currently**
[image]

Comment: Both motors should have wiring diagrams printed on them. Just match them up. Follow the wires from those splices, back to the control board, or check the schematic. That will tell you how to wire everything.

Comment: According to the new motor White = L1 (neutral), Black = High speed, Blue = Medium speed, Red = Low speed. Check the diagram on the old motor, to figure out which wires are which. From what I can see, looks like on the old motor: Black = High speed, Yellow = Medium high, Orange = Medium Low, Red = Low speed.

Comment: Yes, and that is what i had done. The problem is there is an extra setting (orange wire) on the old motor that isn't there on the new one (medium low).

Comment: Probably not all the speeds were used, you'll have to check where they connect to the control board. Most likely, one or two go to a `PARK` terminal, which means they're not used. Heat mode probably should use low, or medium low speed.

Comment: According to [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.icmcontrols.com/prodimages/ig_lii318-2.pdf&ved=0CDoQFjAAahUKEwjupIHsq-7IAhXK6yYKHW8gCy4&usg=AFQjCNF0N4R9npK-FQc8tKDw12BocirEsg&sig2=p8RHW3QqhRQBZLSPK1ViKw), the High speed wire should go to the COOL terminal, and the Medium High (Medium on new motor probably), should go to HEAT. But to be sure, you'll have to check the schematic on your unit, and verify that the new blower speeds are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the research. I'll verify it is connected properly tomorrow.

Comment: Also, there is typically a time delay (based on temperature) from when your heat source turns on, to when your blower actually begins to operate. This is on purpose - people don't like cold air being pumped throughout their living space when they select "heat."

Comment: When the heat is on, wait for the delay 30-90 seconds, depending on the jumpers). Then check for line voltage between the white, and the orange wires. Then check between white and yellow. If you have voltage on one of them, connect the blue wire to it. If you don't have voltage on either, the problem is with the fan control circuitry (probably a fuse, relay, limit, or something else on the control board).

Comment: Why are you replacing the motor?

Comment: @Tester101, that worked! I tested the voltage when the thermostat was calling for heat. The orange wire was pulling voltage so I attached the blue wire to the orange wire in lieu of the yellow. It worked! Thank you for your help! I replaced the blower motor because it went bad last year and didn't function. Thanks.

Comment: Just keep an eye on the system, and make sure it's not overheating. If you notice that the high limit starts to trip, you might have to get a motor with a higher medium speed.

Answer (score 2):

Check the resistance from the White wire (neutral) to each wire.  The higher the resistance, the lower the motor speed.

Example :

- White to Black: Check resistance, write it down.
- White to Red, White to Blue, etc.
- The higher the resistance, the slower the speed.

Black is "generally" HIGH speed. Red Is "generally" the lowest speed. This is NOT always the case. ALWAYS check resistance to verify the proper wiring speed.

- Brown wires (Brown & Brown with White stripe): Usually go to capacitor on 120 Volt motors

Cooling mode "generally" calls for the highest speed.  Heating mode "generally" calls for Medium to Medium High.  Depends on the furnace AND the manufacturer specs for Heat Temp Rrise.

Always check Temp rise on all blower replacement.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You've answered a bunch of questions in the last few hours: many thanks. However, it would be great if you could put a bit of time into formatting your answer; that would let visitors better understand the great info you're bringing here. (Keep 'em coming!)

Answer (score 1):

I just finished replacing the GE motor in my unit with a Mars blower motor. I had the same issue, one extra wire. But there’s a chance the orange wire is actually the common wire and the yellow is one of the two med settings (med hi or med lo). That turned out to be the case in my unit. On my new motor, I had black, red, blue, and yellow. On the old one, it had the extra orange as well. So here is how mine is wired and works correctly:
New motor.                 Unit Side
Black-hi.                      Black-hi
Blue-med.                    Blue-med
Red-lo.                         Red-lo
Yellow-common.         Orange-common

So that’s black to black, blue to blue, red to red, yellow to orange. The yellow wire on the unit side is dead ended (goes nowhere but has a wire nut to prevent any possible short).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: perhaps your furnace needs the speed that is disabled. if it senses that, it will not go into heat mode. for example, this could happen if a 3-speed motor is used to replace a 4-speed motor, and the installer choose which speed to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your fan limit switch on your furnace is working (turn on thermostat to high and fan to auto and listen for furnace to start heating and watch the dial in your fan limit switch to start moving- blower should start at the first, lowest temp setting).